# modifying variable in an array and then reinserting it

Tags: php, arrays

Hi all basically I want to take a value from an array, modify it and then insert it as a new variable in the array. I kind of imagine it looking like follows but as I have never really worked with arrays I have no idea.

```
<?php
    $foobar = array(
        "foo" => "foo1",
        "bar" => "bar1",
    )

 $New_variable = "<img src="$foobar["foo"])">";

 $foobar[foo_img] = $New_variable;
 print_r $foobar;
?>
```

Hope that makes sense and thankyou in advance.

Comment: you cant concatenate strings like that. it should be `"<img src=".$foobar["foo"].">";`

Comment: Did you try anything already? It doesn't seem so.

Comment: Yeah I did, and kept getting errors, I have never worked with arrays before and am now going to have a look at concatenating strings. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are syntax errors in your code.

Try this

```
$foobar = array(
        "foo" => "foo1",
        "bar" => "bar1"
);

$New_variable = "<img src='".$foobar['foo']."'>";

$foobar['foo_img'] = $New_variable;
print_r($foobar);
```

Comment: You missed one in second last line

Comment: @ToBe Technically, `foo_img` *could* be a constant.

Comment: $foobar[foo_img] can be given, its not mandatory to put "foo_img" in quotes

Comment: If it's a constant, your right. If not, it's not good practice and would actually rise E_NOTICE. IMHO every dev should have E_NOTICE enabled on his system.

Comment: agreed, added the quotes.

Comment: thanks that is very helpful, the php manual did not say anything regarding E_Notice and the example they gave was without the quotes.

Comment: cool...accept and close the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Question is  vague, but still try this,

```
$new_variable = "<img src=".$foobar['foo'].">";
$foobar['foo_img'] = $new_variable;
print_r($foobar);
```

Also you can directly do like this to save some lines of code,

```
$foobar['foo_img'] = "<img src=".$foobar['foo'].">";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in 2 steps

```
$foobar['foo_img'] = "<img src=" . $foobar['foo'] . ">";
print_r($foobar);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to save it to a variable first. It's possible to change it directly in the array:

```
<?php
    $foobar = array(
        "foo" => "foo1",
        "bar" => "bar1"
    )

    $foobar["foo"] = "<img src='" . $foobar["foo"] . "'>";
    //                         ^  ^                ^  ^
    // Note concatenation using "." and the ''s 
    // to surround the string in the src attribute 
    print_r($foobar);
?>
```

Comment: thank you for the clear example it was actually the first one to that I understood what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need intermediate steps, and associative arrays are very easy to work with. The solution you're looking for is, directly, inserting the new variable without accounting for what's actually inside the existing array. You can do it like this:

```
$foobar["foo_img"] = "<img src=\"{$foobar["foo"]}\">";
```

As you can see, you don't even need to make a string separation. Hope that helps ;)

Comment: Thanks Going to have compare the use of "\" with "."